# How to simulate PHP image creation feature in java script

Tags: javascript

How to simulate this same image creation feature in java script. i came across with canvas but this will work only on the HTML5. how to createimage in javascript

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/png");
$im = @imagecreate(110, 20)
    or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  "A Simple Text String", $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

some of i crossed: [sampleone](http://jsfiddle.net/JUWrV/)

Comment: Is this for some live preview of an image, when a user inputs a string?

Comment: If canvas is not an option, I believe you only have two options left: SVG or manipulate the raw bytes to generate a data URL. Are those acceptable?

Comment: i want to convert the specific text which inside DIV into image. how to make the string image or create image string in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [fakeimage](http://fakeimg.pl/) is an option. It's a webservice written in python so don't expect a javascript library.
You can provide a text and set the font, color and background color and of course the image size as you want.